# How do I get Python selenium to select a particular input when there are multiple inputs with identical names?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-unittest

I am coding a unittest to automate the selection of a particular time slot from a website.

The HTML code contains multiple inputs corresponding to different days and all these inputs have the same name. Currently I have only managed to select the "Book" button for the next available day. How do I select the "Book" button for a later day.

This is the HTML code. Each input is part of a separate form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/bookings1/Book.php?CWID=1388&amp;intCompID=123790">
<input type="submit" name="Book" value="    Book">
```

This is the Python code I have used which succeeds in selecting the first input.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='Book']").click()
```

How should I proceed to select subsequent inputs?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you share your url?

Comment: @KunduK sadly not since it is a members only part of a website so would need my details

Comment: Use `find_elements_by_xpath` to get all buttons, and iterate over them, or use a specific index.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen how should I index in this case?

Comment: Depending on the location of the buttons, you can sort them for example by their x coordinate, and then use an index to get the wanted one.